Firefox issues showing Confluence pages
I am using firefox 132.0 (64-bit) and I am trying to access a Confluence webpage.
I noticed that a portion of the confluence webpage is not being showed to me, but when I edit the page I can see all of its content. This is, in edit mode I have a COnfluence Section, inside it I have some text - titles, paragraphs, images and macros. But once I leave edit mode I can see that the page isn't full loading as I can only see s part of the section (not all).
I am getting this warnings in the console:
Use of `window._` through AUI is deprecated and will be removed in AUI 10.0.0

DEPRECATED undefined - AJS.params has been deprecated since 9.0.0 and will be removed in 10.0.0.

DEPRECATED JS - AJS.debounce has been deprecated since 8.0.0 and will be removed in 10.0.0. Use equivalent functions from libraries like lodash / underscore instead


Properties of "AJS.Confluence.QuickEdit" were overwritten

DEPRECATED JS - Inline dialog constructor has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use inline dialog 2 instead. 

DEPRECATED JS - AJS.debounce has been deprecated since 8.0.0 and will be removed in 10.0.0. Use equivalent functions from libraries like lodash / underscore instead  

Remove legacy sidebar code when upgrade to AUI 5.8+

DEPRECATED JS - AJS.debounce has been deprecated since 8.0.0 and will be removed in 10.0.0. Use equivalent functions from libraries like lodash / underscore instead  

DEPRECATED JS - AJS.debounceImmediate has been deprecated since 8.0.0 and will be removed in 10.0.0. Use equivalent functions from libraries like lodash / underscore instead  

Not sure if this is related to my issue.
Any as any idea why is this happening?
Note:
If I test this webpage in brave it shows everything.
In Firefox I disabled all the extensions and cleaned cookies. But still was not enough.
Can anyone help me with this? Or any clues how I can fix this or look for something?

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-88208
